# trouble creating a type list in C++98 without macros

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, c++98

So I'm reading [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813) from Andrei Alexandrescu about how to create type lists but the following code from the article does not compile with MSVC/GCC:

```
template <class H, class T>
struct typelist
{
    typedef H head;
    typedef T tail;
};

class null_typelist {};

template <class T1>
struct cons<T1, null_typelist, null_typelist,
    null_typelist>
{
    typedef typelist<T1, null_typelist> type;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct cons<T1, T2, null_typelist, null_typelist>
{
    typedef typelist<T1, typelist<T2,
        null_typelist> > type;
};

template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct cons<T1, T2, T3, null_typelist>
{
    typedef typelist<T1, typelist<T2, typelist<T3,
        null_typelist> > > type;
};

template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
struct cons
{
    typedef typelist<T1, typelist<T2, typelist<T3, 
        typelist<T4, null_typelist> > > > type;
};

typedef cons<float, double, long double>::type
    floating_point_types;
```

I get the following errors:

```
a.cpp:21:8: error: 'cons' is not a class template
 struct cons<T1, null_typelist, null_typelist,
        ^~~~
a.cpp:28:49: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 1)
 struct cons<T1, T2, null_typelist, null_typelist>
                                                 ^
a.cpp:22:18: note: provided for 'template<class T1> struct cons'
     null_typelist>
                  ^
a.cpp:35:38: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 1)
 struct cons<T1, T2, T3, null_typelist>
                                      ^
a.cpp:22:18: note: provided for 'template<class T1> struct cons'
     null_typelist>
                  ^
a.cpp:42:8: error: redeclared with 4 template parameters
 struct cons
        ^~~~
a.cpp:22:18: note: previous declaration 'template<class T1> struct cons' used 1
template parameter
     null_typelist>
                  ^
a.cpp:48:40: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 1)
 typedef cons<float, double, long double>::type
                                        ^
a.cpp:22:18: note: provided for 'template<class T1> struct cons'
     null_typelist>
                  ^
a.cpp:49:5: error: expected initializer before 'floating_point_types'
     floating_point_types;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I need this in C++98 for a library that I'm writing and anything more like variadic templates or third-party like `boost::mpl` is not an option.

So what is the problem? I'm not much into template metaprogramming (yet)...

Comment: No, this just doesn't work. Andrei wrote some of his material at a time when none of the compilers understood the code, so he couldn't have it checked. This might be one example of such code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if can work in msvc (but work with my g++) but, in your code, you declare `cons` partial specializations.

So, before the first partial specialization (off topic: I suggest the use of `typename` instead of `class` for template parameters)

```
template <typename T1>
struct cons<T1, null_typelist, null_typelist,
    null_typelist>
{
    typedef typelist<T1, null_typelist> type;
};
```

you should insert the generic declaration that I suppose can be someting like

```
template <typename,
          typename = null_typelist,
          typename = null_typelist,
          typename = null_typelist>
struct cons;
```